# The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator when i getting third time call

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, custom-list, csom

I know this Question already asked before but that not solved my problem.

But I am facing this error when I make web call third time.

First and second time its give proper data.

**Explanation:** I am trying to get date wise data. I have 3,00,000 data in my sharepoint list. Now I have to fetch today data when user click on today date that working fine and I am get data also. same way 1th march data also  i am getting proper.But before it if I select 28feb date and try to fetch data then its show me this error.

My CAML query like below:

```
<View><Query><Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='Date'/><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2017-02-28T04:00:00Z</Value></Geq><And><Leq><FieldRef Name='Date'/><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2017-02-28T04:10:00Z</Value></Leq><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='EmployeeID'  LookupId='TRUE'/><Value Type='Lookup'>7</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Deleted1' /><Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value></Eq></And></And></And></Where></Query><RowLimit>4999</RowLimit></View>
```

i have run second caml query in SharePoint list(include data:-300000).

```
<View><Query><Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='Date'/><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>" + date1 + "</Value></Geq><And><Leq><FieldRef Name='Date'/><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>" + date2 + "</Value></Leq><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='" + cmn.EmployeeName
+ "'  LookupId='TRUE'/><Value Type='Lookup'>" + Common.EmployeeRowID + "</Value></Eq>" + cmn.DeletedQuery + "</And></And></And></Where></Query><RowLimit>4999</RowLimit></View>;
```

this caml query view result of 10 minute data for specific Time(like 4.10 AM to 4.20 AM) and output display 10 Data for request for same list Successfully.

But First one caml query pass the date and view result of date wise record  disply 60 data then above error display.

Any help will highly appreciated.

Comment: You get this error if your request queries more than 5000 items (default). CAML query works 'step-by-step', so your first `<Where>` statement has to return less than 5000 items. In this case, if `<Geq><FieldRef Name='Date'/><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2017-02-28T04:00:00Z</Value></Geq>` returns more than 5000, it breaks and doesn't even apply the other filters wrapped with `<And>`s. Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: furthermore think of the effect indexing can have on throttling. Microsoft describes it in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798465.aspx

Comment: I have pass column in caml query and this column already indexing in sharepoint list but above query  run after display  error  "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator".

Comment: i have run second caml query in SharePoint list(include data:-300000) .

Comment: If you run second query what happen?. What error show?